# Intersections : problem in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections

What's wrong with the following code ?

```
\documentclass[border=10mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\arcA{(0,-4) arc (90:0:4)};
\def\arcB{(4,-4) arc (90:180:4)};
\draw\arcA;
\draw\arcB;
% the two arcs intersect at a single point
\path [name intersections={of=\arcB and \arcA, by={Int}}];
\draw (Int) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT.** For some reason the following works

```
\documentclass[border=10mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [name path=arcA] (0,-4) arc (90:0:4) ;
\draw [name path=arcB] (4,-4) arc (90:180:4) ;
% \draw arcA : produces an error ...
% \draw arcB : produces an error ...
\path [name intersections={of=arcB and arcA, by={Int}}];
\draw (Int) circle (2pt) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But this *doesn't* work :

```
\documentclass[border=10mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path [name path=arcA] (0,-4) arc (90:0:4) ;
\path [name path=arcB] (4,-4) arc (90:180:4) ;
\draw (arcA) ;
\draw (arcB) ;
\path [name intersections={of=arcB and arcA, by={Int}}];
\draw (Int) circle (2pt) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is solution `\documentclass[tikz, border=10mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[name path=A] (0,-4) arc (90:  0:4);%\arcA;
\draw[name path=B]  (4,-4) arc (90:180:4);%\arcB;
% the two arcs intersect at a single point
\draw [name intersections={of=A and B, by={Int}}]
      (Int) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}` acceptable?

Comment: Dear Zarko : I think we have a similar solution, but I only found mine by blindly permuting things ... Why is it that yours works ? In particular, why is it that using `\draw` instead of `\path` or `\def` works ?

Comment: see my answer below.  `\draw [name intersections={of=A and B, by={Int}}] (Int) circle (2pt); ` is just shorter version of code `\path [name intersections={of=A and B, by={Int}}];
\draw     (Int) circle (2pt);`. The result is at both codes the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You havew many issues in your code:

- `\def...` can not be ended by semicolumn
- you not defined path names
- path names had not to be macros/commands

Try:

```
\documentclass[border=10mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\arcA{(0,-4) arc (90:0:4)}
\def\arcB{(4,-4) arc (90:180:4)}
\draw[name path=A] \arcA;
\draw[name path=B] \arcB;
\draw [name intersections={of=B and A, by={Int}}] 
      (Int) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

or usual way:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[name path=A] (0,-4) arc (90:  0:4);%\arcA;
\draw[name path=B]  (4,-4) arc (90:180:4);%\arcB;
% the two arcs intersect at a single point
\draw [name intersections={of=A and B, by={Int}}]
      (Int) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Both examples gives the same result:

[image]

Comment: Great stuff! This does the trick : ) thanks !