# \def \mypath { ... } versus \path [name path = mypath] ... ;

Tags: tikz-pgf, naming, tikz-path

This question is a follow-up to [my last question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/370484/intersections-problem-in-tikz). It concerns the problem of naming paths in such a way as to be able to perform operations on them such as

1. translating or rotating them
2. calculating intersections

Why is it that the following code produces an error `no shape pathone is known`

```
\documentclass[border=10mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path [name path = pathone]     (0,0) -- ++ (2,2) ;
\draw [ultra thick] (pathone) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

while this works, calculates intersections but doesn't allow for shifting pathone

```
\documentclass[border=10mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [name path = pathone, ultra thick]     (0,0) -- ++ (2,2) ;
\draw [name path = pathtwo, ultra thick]     (0,0) ++ (-0.4,0) -- ++ (2.4,2.4) ;
\draw [name path = pathtre, ultra thick]     (0,0) arc (180:90:2) ;
\draw [name intersections={of=pathtwo and pathtre, by={a, b}}]
      (a) circle (2pt)
      (b) circle (4pt) ;
% \draw [shift={(1,0)}] (pathone) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

while this code allows one to shift, but no intersections ...

```
\documentclass[border=10mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def \pathone {(0,0) -- ++ (2,2)}
\def \pathtwo {(0,0) ++ (-0.4,0) -- ++ (2.4,2.4)}
\def \pathtre {(0,0) arc (180:90:2)}
\draw [ultra thick] \pathone ;
\draw [ultra thick] \pathtwo ;
\draw [ultra thick] \pathtre ;
% \draw [name intersections={of=\pathtwo and \pathtre, by={a, b}}]
%       (a) circle (2pt)
%       (b) circle (4pt) ;
\draw [ultra thick, shift={(1,0)}] \pathone ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and this code does everything :

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def \pathone {(0,0) -- ++ (2,2)}
\def \pathtwo {(0,0) ++ (-0.4,0) -- ++ (2.4,2.4)}
\def \pathtre {(0,0) arc (180:90:2)}
\draw [ultra thick] \pathone ;
\draw [ultra thick, name path = pathtwo] \pathtwo ;
\draw [ultra thick, name path = pathtre] \pathtre ;
\draw [name intersections={of=pathtwo and pathtre, by={a, b}}]
        (a) circle (2pt)
        (b) circle (4pt);
\draw [ultra thick, shift={(1,0)}] \pathone ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

---

1. What does`\path [name path = mypath] ... ;`  do ?
2. What kind of object is `mypath` (presumably it is a path) ?
3. How do I summon `mypath` later on, and perform operations on it ?
4. Why can't I draw the path `mypath` later, yet can use `mypath` to calculate intersections ?
5. When should I use `\def \mypath { ... }` ?
6. Is `\mypath` even a path ?
7. Why is it I can manipulate `\mypath` (such as shifting it) but seemingly can't intersect it with some other path ?

In the end I'm interested in the question

> What is the best way to define a path and giving it a name if I want to be able to use a given path later, possibly move it around etc ... ?

Comment: There are three layers: **Top** = Ti*k*Z = `\path(0,0)--(10pt,10pt);`; **Middle** = PGF = `\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{10pt}{10pt}}`; **Bottom** = PGFsys = `\pgfsyssoftpath@moveto{0pt}{0pt}\pgfsyssoftpath@lineto{10pt}{10pt}`. The transformation (including shifting) happens between **middle** and **bottom**. `name path` and intersecting paths happen at **bottom**. `\def` is purely **top**.

Comment: 1. it stores the softpath tokens (`\pgfsyssoftpath@xxxxxx`) in to a macro called `\tikz@intersect@path@name@mypath`. 2. it is a sequence of softpath tokens. 3. you can only apply softpath operations. For example `rounded corners` and `intersections` happen at this level. 4. in fact you can. 5. when you know what you are doing. 6. sort of. It is a softpath. 7 a Ti*k*Z path should be translated into a softpath before calculating intersection.